# Searching in Array of complex collection of NSDictionary

Tags: nsdictionary

I have an array of dictionaries, similar to the following:

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "category_id": "1",
      "parent_id": "0",
      "en_name": "Category 1",
      "sub": [
        {
          "category_id": "2",
          "parent_id": "1",
          "en_name": "Abc Pqr",
          "businessCount": "5"
        },
        {
          "category_id": "5",
          "parent_id": "1",
          "en_name": "Xyz Model",
          "businessCount": "7"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category_id": "3",
      "parent_id": "0",
      "en_name": "Category 2",
      "sub": [
        {
          "category_id": "4",
          "parent_id": "1",
          "en_name": "Test",
          "businessCount": "15"
        },
        {
          "category_id": "6",
          "parent_id": "1",
          "en_name": "Dummy",
          "businessCount": "9"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to search for "en_name" of element "sub". Please suggest me ASAP

Answer (score 0):

i am assuming that you have the categories array...that u got from webApi..

then enumerating that categories array...as it is the array of dictionaries....
then sub also an array of dictioanries..enumerating that will give u that u want...

```
for(NSDictionary *dict in categories)
    {
      for(NSDictionary * dict1 in [dict objectForKey :@"sub"])
      {
         NSString *name = [dict1 objectForKey :@"en_name"];

       }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.